# edit page is not showing select option as selected in backpack laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am beginner in backpack laravel. The edited form does not set selected value by default.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UltYq.png)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: If you want to get helped please follow this guide to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask